# C# - SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() gets more entries from database, then the same query directly

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I wrote a query in SQL Server Management Studio and saved it. Then I wrote this code:

```
static public List<DataRow> SendQuery(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(reader);

        List<DataRow> rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        return rows;
    }
}
```

and ran it. To my surprise `rows` had more items then actual number of rows that I got when ran the same query in SSMS.

Comparing data is not an option because there is too much of it. Why is it happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: You can use sql profiler and check sql queries. Are you sure sql parameters type is correct maybe it produces different output due to type error.

Comment: You have to show the query that you have used in the database. Maybe we can tell you then where the issue is.

Comment: Why do you think it's happening on the C# side of the connection? It's very hard for us to provide advice here when perhaps the most important thing - the query - is glaringly absent from the question. If I were to guess you've probably got additional row-counting statements before your final select statement and no `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: Aside... `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are also `IDisposable`. i.e.: they should also be in `using` blocks so as to avoid resource leakage.

Comment: If there's too much data to compare, then reduce it by adding filters. In the process you may well discover what the differences between the situations are. To a first approximation, try looking at the rows with a lowest or highest value in a column somewhere.

Comment: `ExecuteReader` *doesn't* change the number of rows. If the results are different it's because either the query or the data is different. You may be connecting to the wrong database too, using a production instead of a dev connection string or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bora Karaca suggestion I figured it out. First of all I can't post query here, because it exposes my DB structure which is IP of my employee. In turned out that passing `Date` parameter to the query is a bit tricky since it passes it with time 0:00:00. When I uses 2023-01-31 in C# it somehow converted it to the end of the day with 23:59:59 but passed 0:00:00 as parameter.